# Which is correct "lean on door" OR "lean against door"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

The questions is self-explanatory. 
I've actually seen "lean on door" to be more frequently used, but I've also heard the latter form.

Is there a difference between these two forms?

Comment: I don't think they have any meaningful difference; if you want to spend time mulling it, *on* simply indicates placement, whereas *against* has a stronger element of force, but the end result is the same.

Comment: Either is fine.  You may find that sometimes one seems a better fit, sometimes the other.  "Lean against" is a bit more precise and less apt to raise the hackles of a nit-picker, though.

Comment: "Lean on door" is missing an article (see [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lean+on+door%2Clean+on+the+door&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clean%20on%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0) for support). Likewise with "lean against door". "Lean on *the* door" would be equivalent to "lean against *the* door".

Answer (score 7):

**lean against**  (transitive lean) =stack, position.

> leaning the pictures against the door to see them better.
>   slammed the door shut and leant /leaned his back against it.
>   *cf* leaned the [ladder against](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leant+against) the wall (free dictionary)

**lean on**  =use force against

> leant on the door until it opened
>   he had to lean on the door to get it to shut properly.

There is considerable overlap in usage, but 'lean *something* on the door' is not found.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from this [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/lean-sth-against-on-sth) the meaning is the same and they can be used interchangeably to refer to a physical posture.

I think the real difference is that ***lean on*** can be used also figuratively in the sense of " having as moral support":

- Everybody needs someone to lean on in times of trouble.

Referring to the two sentences you are suggesting: *lean against vs on the door*, according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lean%20against%20the%20door%2Clean%20on%20the%20door&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clean%20against%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clean%20on%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0) ***lean against*** is more common.